# Writing Google Apps Script declarations more succinctly

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

Can the following `Apps Script` code be expressed in a more succinct manner, with a fewer lines of code?

```
// Return the currently active spreadsheet
var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
// Get a script property store
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()
// Get the ID of the currently active spreadsheet and set it as a property
scriptProperties.setProperty("id", activeSpreadsheet.getId())
// Open a spreadsheet using its ID
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProperties.getProperty("id"))
// Return the first sheet in a spreadsheet
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0];
```